# Do you have to convert query string parameters to data types?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I wanted to know whether you have to convert or cast certain query string or post params to specific data types in order to use them in controllers. For example, if I pass a categoryid (an integer in the database) query string parameter into a controller, do I have to convert it to an integer in my controller using the `to_i` method or does Ruby do this automatically? Also, how do I test query string param values and their data types using the rails console? I can't really tell what's going on with query string or post params as I test my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails (and particularly ActiveRecord) is, in general, relatively tolerant of the datatypes passed. For example, both of these lines will return the User with ID 1:

```
User.find(1)
User.find('1')
```

And the same goes for more complex queries:

```
User.where({ id: '1' })
User.where('id = ?', '1')
```

Parameters come through to the controller as strings, which means you can just call `User.find(params[:id])`, without having to call `params[:id].to_i`.

If you want to inspect the class of a variable in the Rails console, then you can call `.class` on an object. For example:

```
[1] pry(main)> "1".class
=> String
[2] pry(main)> 1.class
=> Fixnum
```

I hope that helps.